# how to enable and disable mouse dragging to avoid collison in unity 3d using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have walls that block player movement in the scene. I want to drag the player when the path is free and disable when the player hits the wall. I can enable and disable with mouseButtonDown(). This enable only when the mouse is pressed. I dont want this.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    if (enableDrag ==false)
        enableDrag = true;
}

OnMouseDrag()
{
    if(enableDrag== true)
    {
        ....
    }
}

.....

void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D coll)
{
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Walls") 
    {
        enableDrag= false;
    }
}
```

Also I dont need unstable motion of the player when it collides with the wall.
Any comment from your experience is heplful.

Comment: Good formatting is your friend. Use it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: You should add the Unity3D tag.

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to enable the drag , but maybe you want to use OnMouseOver() ?

Comment: Basically I am looking for fast way to enable dragging. in my case it depends on input from mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change the logic up. It sounds like you want a constant drag unless colliding with a wall. So you could in that case say:

Pseudo:

Inside your Update()

```
If (not colliding with walls) 
    DragObject()
```

This would require you to know when you are no longer colliding. Perhaps using OnCollisionExit.

Comment: Thanks.That is exactly what I am looking for. Constant dragging unless colliding.I was able to do it. With my logic I have to press down the button to renable the dragging.That means everytime collision happens renabling needs the    mouse press. I don't want enabling drag with mouse press down.

Comment: So were you able to change your logic to make it work without the button press?

Comment: You can use OnCollisionExit2D in order to set enabledrag to false rather than using the button press.

Comment: yes I did.With that the player movement is not smooth when it get collides with the wall. Also with your approach unstable motion of player.

Comment: Can you post your full current code? The instability can be handled, but it depends on how you're doing things currently

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough it is too late to answer, here is how I solved the problem.With this approach you can drag the player continously  as far it is not colliding with obstacles.

```
void OnMouseOver ()
    {

    Vector2 mousePos;

    Vector3 mousePosWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        mousePos.x = mousePosWorld.x;
        mousePos.y = mousePosWorld.y;
        this.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, new Vector3 (mousePosWorld.x, mousePosWorld.y, 0), speed * Time.deltaTime);



        if (enableDrag) {

            Vector3 cursorPoint = new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0);
            Vector3 cursorPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (cursorPoint) + offset;
            transform.position = new Vector3 (cursorPosition.x, cursorPosition.y, 0);



        }


If void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D coll)
{
 if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Obstacle") 
 {
     enableDrag= false;
  }
}
```